# NPN transistor doesn't work when base gets more voltage

Tags: transistors, remote-control

I'm working on a project to control my tv with voice commands. I disassembled the remote control and i want to replace the physical switches that are beneath the buttons with transistors, so that i can turn them on and off without physically pressing buttons. When i connect the base to one of the other buttons of the remote to try it, it lets current through and the button is "pressed", when i connect the base to a battery, either with or without a resistor, it doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: If you connect the base-emitter junction to a battery without a resistor, (forward biassed), you no longer have a transistor. Fit a new one.

Comment: `when i connect the base to a battery, either with or without a resistor, it doesn't do anything at all.` If you don't use a resistor then you short the battery with BE junction, most likely you burn the transistor. From then on, if you don't replace the transistor, it doesn't matter if you use a resistor.

Comment: I tried several more transistors with a resistor, connected to varying voltages, but none worked.

Comment: Transistors don't respond to voice commands. Random connection of transistors to a circuit is unlikely to give good results and even if it did you wouldn't know why. You need a schematic of the controller and then some proper theory of operation.

Comment: The voice command part i have handled of course. I couldn't find a schematic anywhere, I will keep looking though and try to figure it out somehow.

Comment: @šabrak - Hi, This seems to be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Instead of asking about the problems connecting a transistor, I suggest you ask how to connect a remote control unit to whatever MCU / SBC you are using. Do you *have* to use a transistor, or are any solutions acceptable? You mention that you have the voice control part handled. So if I was in your situation, I would "go up a level" and look at the several previous topics here about how to interface to a remote controller from MCU, RPi etc instead of asking about transistors. See what I mean?

Comment: Using a MOSFET rather than a bipolar transistor is liable to be more effective. Depending on the circuitry you MAY need a bidirectional switch. If not you still need correct polarity with a bipolar.  Even with a MOSFET te available voltages may not make it easy to turn a transistor on an off. | Are you able to provide a circuit and/or waveforms?